# How do i become href out of a link

Tags: javascript, php, html

Following problem:
I would like to not have to copy my navigation bar over every site. So I wrote it in an extra Document and included it with php. The site ur on has a special class to show its active now that where I'm stuck at. I tried following statement just to see if my idea works

```
<script> if(document.getElementById("test").href == window.location.pathname){window.alert("wow");}
```

Spoiler alert it does not:(

I know that the pathname is the same as href(tried it) but I can't get the href like that. Does anybody know how to do that? Sorry for my English

Thanks a lot for helping

PS: I'm just getting into js I usually work with other languages but wanted to get into website design.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @LordPaulHD please try to break your question in multiple parts, and add more info.

Comment: Just do `alert(window.location.pathname)` instead and you will immediately see why it's not equal to the href. As for solving this, you should consider a different approach entirely. Most people who move from .html to .php simply rename their files. But a way better solution is to instead of `projects.php` etc. use `index.php?page=projects` and use `$_GET['page']` to include the main part of each page instead.

Comment: rather than look for a single link then check if the current path is it's href, which would always fire if the element exists, get all the links in the nav and then loop over them, then set the class to active for that specific link

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple : `document.getElementById("test").href` gives out the whole link with www even thoug its not standing in there while `window.location.pathname` just gives out the path like /index.php. I had to use `window.location.href` instead.

Thanks for all the answers